# Printing a list of right justified separated numbers with no trailing space in python

Tags: python-3.x, printing, separator, trailing, right-justified

```
for i in range(7):
    print("{0:>2}".format(i), sep = " ", end="")
```

My `sep = " "` is not being taken into account.
I do not want to use `str.join()`, and I would prefer to not have to create and add to a string each time the loop is run.

Please help me solve!

Answer (score 0):

You code has multiple problems.  The { outside the format string is a syntax error.  You need a pair {} in the format string.  You should use conversion type d for an int.  Sep only applies if there is more than one field.  End determines what is printed after each print statement.  I expect the following is what you want.

```
for i in range(7):
    print("{0:>2d}".format(i), end=" ")
# prints
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6
```

EDIT: Avoiding a final space is only slightly harder.

```
start = True
for i in range(7):
    print('' if start else ' ', "{0:>2d}".format(i), sep='', end='')
    start = False
# prints
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6
```

Comment: Hi Jeff. Thanks for your response! Sorry, I sloppily wrote up what I wanted. Your output is correct, but I am trying to eliminate the final space after the last int.